# EntityManager.merge not doing anything

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have a User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "bi_user" )
@SequenceGenerator( name = "USER_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "USER_SEQUENCE" )
public class User
        extends DataObjectAbstract<Long>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7870157016168718980L;

    /**
     * key for this instance. Should be managed by JPA provider.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ_GEN" )
    private Long key;

    /**
     * Username the user will use to login.  This should be an email address
     */
    @Column( nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String username;

    // etc. other columns and getters/setters
}
```

Where DataObjectAbstract is a simple `@MappedSuperClass` that has a jpa version and equals/hashcode definition.

I have a base dao class that looks like this

```
public abstract class BaseDaoAbstract<T extends DataObject<K>, K extends Serializable>
        implements BaseDao<T, K>
{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Save a new entity. If the entity has already been persisted, then merge
     * should be called instead.
     * 
     * @param entity The transient entity to be saved.
     * @return The persisted transient entity.
     */
    @Transactional
    public T persist( T entity )
    {
        em.persist( entity );
        return entity;
    }

    /**
     * merge the changes in this detached object into the current persistent
     * context and write through to the database. This should be called to save
     * entities that already exist in the database.
     * 
     * @param entity The entity to be merged
     * @return The merged entity.
     */
    @Transactional
    public T merge( T entity )
    {
        return em.merge( entity );
    }

    // other methods like persist, delete, refresh, findByKey that all delegate to em.
}
```

I have defined the OpenEntityManagerInView filter in web.xml as follows

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>biEmf</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I recently upgrade to eclipselink 2.3.2 and Spring 3.1 and converted from CGLIB proxies to Load Time Weaving with aspectJ for Spring but I did not configure LTW for eclipselink.

The problem is in this code which lives in a spring ApplicationListener, see comments.

```
        User user = userService.findByKey(userDetails.getKey());

        // THIS MERGE NEVER WRITES THROUGH TO THE DATABASE.
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK AS PERSIST EITHER
        user = userService.merge( user.loginSuccess() );
```

user.loginSuccess just sets some fields and returns `this`  I'm certain it's getting through the code because I get log statements around it and I can set a breakpoint and walk through it.  My postgres log doesn't show any traffic getting to postgres for the merge.

I am saving other stuff all over the place without issue, including users in another location when they change their password, and I know this code used to work.  Is there something obviously amiss here?  Am I using the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter incorrectly?  Should I need to be in a @Transactional method in order for the entities to be considered managed?  Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
I tried the flush as suggested by prajeesh.  Here's the code

```
@Transactional
public T merge( T entity )
{
    entity = em.merge( entity );
    em.flush();
    return entity;
}
```

in a class in `com.bi.data`.  I have this in my spring app config file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bi.controller,com.bi.data,com.bi.web" />
```

In my spring configuration I have

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

with an aop.xml that looks like this:

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.bi..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

and I got a

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
```

So something is obviously misconfigured, but what?

**Update 2:**
I reverted my changes to enable load time weaving and now the merge goes through with or without the flush, but I still don't understand what the problem is with LTW...

Comment: Does seem like you have transaction configured correctly.  Perhaps include your persistence.xml, ensure you are using RESOURCE_LOCAL.  Enable logging on finest to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas James.  I'll have a look at it after work.  I'm pretty certain we are using RESOURCE_LOCAL because we are running in tomcat so never did JTA.

Comment: Have you tried adding propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED to the @Transactional annotation?

Comment: I did not try that. went with my change in update 2 of the question and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 14):

Try the `em.flush()` also after the `em.merge()`. Sometimes the `EntityManager` just keeps the the changes for updating later.

Answer (score 4):

EntityManager autocommit is false. Please use transaction like below;

```
EntityManager em = null;
EntityTransaction t = null;
try {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    t = em.getTransaction();
    t.begin();
    em.merge(myTestObject);
    t.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    t.rollback();
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}finally{
    if(em != null)
        em.close();
}
```

Comment: i am using jpa and it doesn't allow em.getTransaction(),

Comment: Sometimes JPA can not find persistence.xml file in path. Where your persistence.xml path? If your em is null, move persistence.xml  to src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml

Answer (score 3):

I had the very issue and got resolved by changing the scope.

```
@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

ref: [Manipulating Entities with EntityManager](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/ejb/ejb3_manipulating.htm)

Comment: I search for this solution several months, in a big project thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `transaction.begin()` and `transaction.end()` methods? In RESOURCE_LOCAL you should manage the transaction and not the application...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is the following line in your Spring configuration file:
 
This enables @Transactional annotation support, and also make sure that mode="proxy", **not mode="aspectj"** is set